# Problem with ZK CacheMap

Tags: java, zk

my application saves a Map , this some times made `JavaHeapSpace`  Error. 
i used `org.zkoss.util.CacheMap` instead [it's JDoc](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/3.5.2/zcommon/org/zkoss/util/CacheMap.html)

but i am not sure if it solves the problem or not?

Comment: Can you try to form a coherent question, perhaps with some simple sample code. We really need a little bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

ZK CacheMap will remove old entities once GC starts (i.e., the memory running low), so it shall help. But, make sure it is OK the removal of old entities is what you want.

Comment: i don't want to remove any object in MAP

Comment: Then, CacheMap is not for you. Why not using HashMap if you'd like to preserve all entities?